# Running fortran code with imput file from python

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

What I am interested in, is to have my python code run this unix command line:

```
./code < file
```

The code is fortran, but I believe I should avoid using F2PY. One, the output of the fortran code are files, and I have other codes whose job is to read them. And two, I want to keep it as simple as possible. The file is just a regular input file that my fortran code can read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modern way of doing this would be to simply use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

```py
import subprocess
with open("file") as f:
    subprocess.run("path_to_script", stdin=f)
```

Note that I'm just passing the file descriptor and not reading it within Python.